# Split calculation string into parts

Tags: beginner, c, parsing, homework

Our professor has given us the following task (its part of a bigger document full of tasks):

Write a function in C that handles strings like "233+343" and parse them into the variables "iNum1", "cOp" and "iNum2". (I tried to translate it into english).

We mostly program in Java and my C knowledge consists of mostly provisional half knowledge.

But is my program beautiful enough to show it to a professor?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ASCII_POS_OF_0 0x30
#define ASCII_POS_OF_9 0x39

void parse_calc_string(char string[])
{

    // get first number
    int iNum1 = 0;
    int index = 0;
    char current_char = string[index];
    while (current_char >= ASCII_POS_OF_0 && current_char <= ASCII_POS_OF_9)
    {
        iNum1 *= 10;
        iNum1 += (int)current_char - ASCII_POS_OF_0;
        current_char = string[++index];
    }

    // get operation symbol
    char cOp = current_char;
    current_char = string[++index];

    // get second number
    int iNum2 = 0;
    while (current_char >= ASCII_POS_OF_0 && current_char <= ASCII_POS_OF_9)
    {
        iNum2 *= 10;
        iNum2 += (int)current_char - ASCII_POS_OF_0;
        current_char = string[++index];
    }

    printf("iNum1: %i\n", iNum1);
    printf("cOp  : %c\n", cOp);
    printf("iNum2: %i\n", iNum2);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    parse_calc_string("219+43");
    parse_calc_string("195-143");
    parse_calc_string("15*13");
    parse_calc_string("212/14");
}
```

Comment: This question (or more correctly the aspect that this is homework which has not been handed in yet) is being discussed on meta: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/the-ethics-of-answering-a-homework-question-before-it-is-handed-in, please voice your opinions regarding that matter there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the value for `ASCII_POS_OF_0` easily by using `'0'`.

Your code doesn't deal with malformed strings well.

If the string is only `"123"` it will attempt to read beyond the contents of the string. You can fix this by checking for `'\0'` at the correct places.

It also doesn't handle any type of whitespace in the string at all.

Comment: Exception handling and handling whitespace was not included in the task. Also it would bloat up this little task.

Answer (score 0):

it is a poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.

I.E.  in the posted code, the contents of the header file: `string.h` are not being used.  Suggest removing the statement:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: I think this could be a comment

Comment: @DexterThorn,  in CodeReview, there isn't supposed to be any comments.  Just answers